# Fab icon is going under title bar

Tags: android, floating-action-button

[image]

My fab icon is going under title bar, I tried making the fab size as mini but I am still having this issue. Any suggestions on what I can do about this situation.

```
<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu

        android:id="@+id/multiple_actions"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/colorPrimary"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/white"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_create_invoice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_upload"
            fab:fabSize="mini"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/purple"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/purple"
            fab:fab_title="Create Invoice" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_create_purchase"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_money"
            fab:fabSize="mini"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/purple"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/purple"
            fab:fab_title="Create Purchase" />
</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: post your layout

Comment: code has been added

Comment: no, please post your complete layout file for this activity not only fab

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because your fab elevation is below your appbar. These two attributes control fab elevation. I have set material design recommendations but you could change them if they don't suit you.

```
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
```